# Subsequences with different limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Given is the complex sequence:

$$(a_n)_{n\epsilon \Bbb N} \subset \Bbb C $$ with the subsequences:

$$a_n = 5i^n(1+{1\over n^3})$$

How do I find 5 another subsequences of $$(a_n)_{n\epsilon \Bbb N} $$ with different limits each?

Comment: Hint; use de moievre

Comment: After "subsequences" you write $\;a_n=...\;$ , so: is that **the** sequence or one of the subsequences of **the** sequence?

Comment: @DonAntonio it is the sequence, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, the sequence $(a_n)$ is given by $a_n=5i^n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$. So, $(a_{4n}),(a_{4n+1}),(a_{4n+2}),(a_{4n+3})$ are four subsequences with pairwise distinct limits. I am afraid that $\pm 5, \pm 5i$ are all possible limits of subsequences of this sequence. Indeed, all terms ot our sequence are located on the positive (negative) halfline of real (imaginary) numbers.

Comment: why is it $$a_{4n}$$ ? and not $$a_{n+1}$$